# Codeigniter sharing variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope

I have got a maybe silly question - but that's due to my lack of knowledge. I am wondering if I can accomplish the following result.

**Controller**

```
class Building extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct(){    
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('buildings/buildings_model' , 'buildings');
    $is_locked = $this->buildings->_lock;
}

    // generic building overview. Includes data like name and location
    public function index($obj)
    {

        // the $obj param is the segment id from router
    }

    public function details($obj)
    {
        // here I would get some more specific data
    }

    public function associates($obj)
    {
       // list of things that the object is associated
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
class buildings_model extends MY_Model{
     public $_lock = false;
     function __construct() {   
        parent::__construct();
        // example pseudo code
        // db query select lock from obj where id = 1 for example
        // if lock == 1 { $this->_lock = TRUE; }
     }
}
```

And now the question.. I assigned a global variable `public $_lock = false;`
in the `model` so it's accessible in every scope of the `controller`.
But each time I access the `views`, the `model constructor` each time makes a query to check if Object is locked. Generally I need a global flag if the building is locked - but generated once not every page view.

Comment: store it in session and check set or not that's it.

Comment: well, that something to consider, but will wait for other ideas too, the user can access multiple buildings over the time, so there could be much session stored informations.

Comment: I think db is best place for u to store the flag. u can check if it's true in constructor itself and call die/exit there

Comment: well but it's called every model load, which is quite bad